# Invert the values of a vector using the same vector and two indices

Tags: c++, arrays

Given a number `N` (`<30`), and a vector `VEC` of `N` elements that contain integer values, invert the contents of the vector and report it **using the same vector with two indices**.

---

I have no idea how to implement the code using the given requirements. I have tried the following:

```c++
for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        VEC[i] = VEC[j];
    }
    cout << VEC[i] << "\t";
}
```

but it did not work.

I can only use `iostream` library.

---

As a reference, you can see the same but using another vector with: (1) 1 index, (2) 2 indices:

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void usingAnotherVecWith2Ind(int [], int [], int);
void usingAnotherVecWith1Ind(int [], int [], int);

int main() {
    int N = 0;

    cout << "Enter N: ";
    cin >> N;

    if (N < 30) {
        int VEC[N] = {0}, VEC2[N] = {0};

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            cout << "Enter value " << i << ": ";
            cin >> VEC[i];
        }

        usingAnotherVecWith2Ind(VEC, VEC2, N);

        usingAnotherVecWith1Ind(VEC, VEC2, N);
    }

    return 0;
}

void usingAnotherVecWith2Ind(int VEC[], int VEC2[], int N) {
    cout << endl << "The reverse vector using another vector with 2 indices is:" << endl;
    for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            VEC2[j] = VEC[i];
        }
        cout << VEC2[i] << "\t";
    }
}

void usingAnotherVecWith1Ind(int VEC[], int VEC2[], int N) {
    cout << endl << "The reverse vector using another vector with 1 index is:" << endl;
    for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        VEC2[i] = VEC[i];
        cout << VEC2[i] << "\t";
    }
}
```

Example:

[image: Example]

**EDIT.** I cannot use [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Comment: You might be looking for [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks, but I cannot use that function.

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The question states that only `<iostream>` header can be used.

Comment: Hint: first, figure out how to swap values of two `int` variables.

Comment: i.e. write a function that takes a vector and two integer indices and swaps their positions.   Then write a loop over your vector that repeatedly calls that swap function

Comment: @manooooh The reverse page has a *Possible implementation* part.  Copy that and you're set.  The step through it with your debugger to figure out how it works if you can't tell from the code.

Comment: I have to say that only <iostream> is very restrictive, but it does prevent use of <bits/stdc++.h>

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I was able to do it using a function called `usingSameVecWith2Ind` and an external one called `swap`.

Comment: Why the negative votes?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help in comments I was able to achieve the following:

```c++
void usingSameVecWith2Ind(int VEC[], int N) {   
    cout << endl << "The reverse vector using the same vector with 2 indices is:" << endl;
    for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            swap(VEC[i], VEC[j]);
        }
        cout << VEC[i] << "\t";
    }
}
```

```c++
void swap(int ind1, int ind2) {
    int aux;
    aux = ind1;
    ind1 = ind2;
    ind2 = aux;
}
```